# Верстка html-подписи в Outlook - не могу найти ошибку в CSS

Tags: css, outlook

при получении на mail.ru выдает в стилях такую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<p class="pc-cont-italic" style="margin-top: 1px; margin-bottom: 1px; color: black; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; text-align: left; line-height: 1.3; font-size: 16px; display: block; letter-spacing: -0.5px; font-style: italic;padding: 0;" align="left">Региональный менеджер</p>
```

Если у абзаца выставляю свойство margin-top:1px; то свойство срабатывает - ошибки нет. Как только дополняю абзац свойством margin-bottom:1px; выскакивает данная ошибка.

Куда копать, подскажите, пожалуйста?

Comment: Не уверен на 100%, но мне кажется что это должно быть в <!--[if mso | IE]> ... <!--[if mso | IE]>, и не <p> а таблицей, вот хороший фреймворк для верстки писем https://mjml.io/ .

Comment: Сверстано в Foundation for Emails - табличная верстка.

Comment: Префикс `mso` имеют свойства, которые понимает только сам Outlook. Ну, возможно, ещё Word. Но никто кроме офисного пакета его не поймёт, так что оно закономерно зачёркнуто как неизвестное свойство. UPDATE: Перечитал вопрос, передумал так отвечать.

Comment: не уверен на 100%, прочитай эту  статью  https://tj-s.ru/tod/verstka-pisem.-polnaya-versiya.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спустя сутки проблема решилась вот так:

```
margin: 0pt; //одним свойством за 4 стороны, плюс в pt
```

Яндекс и Mail.ru приняли этот стиль - все отображается, как задумано